# How to uninstall Synology Cloud Station

Tags: 20.04

I recently updated my NAS firmaware to 7.0. With this came the transition from "Cloud Station" to "Synology Drive".
The new Synology Drive client installed just fine on my ubuntu system (20.04).
However the old Cloud Station client is still around, and it tries to initialize itself on each clean startup.
How do I remove it? I don't really see where it gets started either (etc/systemd etc...) so can't really remove it manually.

Answer (score 7):

```
sudo sed -i 's/killall/killall -r/g' /var/lib/dpkg/info/synology-cloud-station.prerm
sudo apt purge synology-cloud-station
```

Comment: This solves the problem, but maybe add a sentence or two explaining the background on why this is needed (the broken prerm script).

Answer (score 0):

You can check installed utilities like this:

1. Open Terminal (if it’s not already open)
2. List anything starting with `syno`:

   ```
   sudo apt list | grep -i syno
   ```
3. Uninstall any packages you don’t want:

   ```
   sudo apt purge {package}
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Be sure to replace `{package}` with the actual package(s) you would like to remove.</sup>

That’s all there is to it

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The process unfortunately stops this way:
`Removing synology-cloud-station (4.3.3-4469) ...
dpkg: error processing package synology-cloud-station (--remove):
 installed synology-cloud-station package pre-removal script subprocess was killed by signal (Terminated)
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 synology-cloud-station
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: I checked, I don't see any syno related process running when I do a `ps -aux`...

Answer (score 0):

Preremove script might have errors, you can add some debug to check which files it is executing and hack them a little bit:

```
sudo dpkg --debug=2 -r synology-cloud-station
```

Just came here after similar error.